# Open source Android app to delete all contacts

Tags: android, open-source, contact-manager

I sometimes want to delete all contacts on my Android phone *(to reimport them from a third-party source)*.

Requirements:

- Open Source
- Progress indicator

And as fast as possible, for thousands of contacts.
I don't use sync.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To delete all contacts stored on Android, you can try:

- turned off sync
- go to settings> applications> manage applications> Contacts storage>clear data.
- turned on sync. It should re-synced to Google/GB/etc contacts

Comment: Actually I don't use sync, so the procedure would be even easier, limited to the 2nd bullet item.

Comment: Not sure about the progress indicator, though #)